# Этимология слова "противень"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Часто говорят "протвинь", но на самом деле — "противень". А каково происхождение этого слова? Оно родственно слову "противный"?))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово «противень» произошло от немецкого слова «Bratpfanne» («сковорода»), которое появилось в русском обиходе в XVIII веке (в период постепенной интернационализации русской кухни) и быстро русифицировалось.[1] В то время для запекания пользовались сковородой без ручки или прямоугольной формой с высокими бортиками, которая в русском языке называлась «судок» или «латка». Противнями стали называть и сковороды без ручек, и «судки». Потом слово «противень» стало обозначать только судок и вытеснило исконные русские наименования...Нашел в интернете.

Comment: Представлю мой изумленный комментарий)
**Braten** -  жарить (нем.) То есть превращать или обращать сырой продукт в съедобно-жареный. Обратный = противный, мои восхищенные рукоплескания русской адаптации  немецкого слова. Виват восемнадцатому веку! **Противень** forever))) Такие вещи надо рассказывать школьникам.

Comment: Ранее, а потом и одновременно,  слово *противень* означало точную копию документа ...
>И. И. Лажечников. Последний Новик (1833) ― Не веришь, взгляни на **противень с указа**, который я имел благополуцие списать слово в слово.

>В. И. Даль. Бедовик (1839) ... похитил в глазах его эту ангельскую головку, закинутую немного назад, когда разглядывала она луну на ущербе, а Лиров в то же время расположился еще, как **противень или дружка**, рядом с верстовым столбом.

Answer (score 3):

"Предыдущие ораторы" не совсем точны. 
Cковородка в немецком просто die Pfanne.
die Brattрfanne - изначально это именно особая сковородка с вертикальными или слегка отогнутыми бортами высотой 1-2 дюйма. Использовалась исключительно для приготовления пирогов и кондитерских изделий с жидкой начинкой. Позже стала ограниченно применяться и для других изделий из теста - и не только. Вот такая-то сковородка "Браттпфанне", постепенно фонетически трансформируясь, и дала имя русскому противню. 
Остальное - согласен.
Версия В. В. Похлебкина по бумажному изданию.