# Все о противне

Tags: этимология

Во-первых, мне интересно, откуда вообще взялось это слово и имеет ли оно что-то общее со словом "противный". Во-вторых, интересно, почему буква И упорно выпадает в этом слове?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не имеет. Это от немецкого Bratpfanne - большая сковорода, изначально - с вертикальными бортами.

//-----------

Противень пришел в нашу кухню почти одновременно с листом, в период устного обучения поварскому ремеслу. По-немецки эта прямоугольная сковорода из железа называлась «браттпанне», то есть сковорода для жарения, для запекания. Она имела довольно высокие борта: от одного дюйма (2, 5 см) до полутора, а иногда и до двух. Эти борта могли быть либо перпендикулярными к плоскости сковороды, либо наклонными, образуя с ней тупой угол.

Первоначально «браттпанне», как трудное для произношения слово, трансформировалось в устном языке в «бротпань», а потом приобрело совсем русскую окраску, превратившись в «противень».

(В. Похлебкин, Тайны хорошей кухни).

Ой, пардон. Оказывается, уже отвечал.
[Этимология слова "противень"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20739/)